Matching not working inside lookup pipeline
My claim_rules collection looks like this
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dba"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 700201
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dbb"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 700202
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dbc"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 700208
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dbd"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 700210
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dbe"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 700219
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "66c3118a234ecb42936c6dbf"},
    "ramo_sx": 1,
    "tipo_sx": 900102
  },
  ...

I am trying to lookup only for specific ramo_sx and tipo_sx fields using a lookup stage with a pipeline like this
{
        $lookup: {
            from: "claim_rules",
            let: { ramo_sx: "$vda.ramo_sx", tipo_sx: "$vda.tipo_sx" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        ramo_sx: "$$ramo_sx",
                        tipo_sx: "$$tipo_sx"
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "claim_rules"
        }
    }

The vda variable is taken from this collection:
[
  {
    "_id": "1-8101-2023-0445722",
    "vda": {
      "ramo_sx": 5,
      "tipo_sx": 31
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "1-8101-2023-0447269",
    "vda": {
      "ramo_sx": 39,
      "tipo_sx": 22
    }
  },
  ...

The problem is that the resulting claim_rules is empty

According to the docs, you must use $expr operator to access the variable. Your $lookup pipeline should as below:
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "claim_rules",
    let: {
      ramo_sx: "$vda.ramo_sx",
      tipo_sx: "$vda.tipo_sx"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$ramo_sx",
                  "$$ramo_sx"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$tipo_sx",
                  "$$tipo_sx"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "claim_rules"
  }
}

Also, it is recommended to place the $match stage as the first stage to utilize the index and have better query performance.
